# TypeOrm multiple Inner Join

Tags: node.js, query-builder, typeorm, node-postgres

I trying to find if a user is either a player or a owner.
So far, i can check one of them with inner join.

A game can have multiple players , and only one owner  (both of them can be define as an USER )

So..this works to find if an USER is a player:

```
const userId = 25;
const gameId = 2;
const resutl = await this.gameRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('game')
  .select('game.id')
  .innerJoin('game.players', 'player', 'player.id = :playerId', {playerId: userId,})
  .where('game.id = :gameId', { gameId: gameId }).getOne()
```

But i cant figured it out, how to check for the owner at the same time...

I have tried something like :

```
const userId = 25;
const gameId = 2;
const resutl = await this.gameRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('game')
  .select('game.id')
  .innerJoin('game.players', 'player', 'player.id = :playerId', {playerId: userId,})
  .innerJoin('game.owner', 'owner', 'owner.id = :ownerId', {ownerId: ownerId,})
  .where('game.id = :gameId', { gameId: gameId }).getOne()
```

But always returns undefined... (nothing)
Maybe i don't need another inner join to check that..maybe addSelect...i'm not sure...some help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a role column in your user entity? I suggest defining a role column and that role could be either owner or player so you can easily make an if statement or an authorization middleware

Comment: I already have roles, but they have other type of intent... i already have some middleware to protect endpoints...it may sounds weird  but let say i got Normal users that can enroll to games as players and also they can create games as owners. And i got a manager role to do things like ban user and other stuff... so it is not a option in this case.

Comment: In your description you said you wanted to identify if a user is either a player or owner right? or i misunderstood something? But if that's not the case then you can easily just say `if(user.role=="owner")` since you already have a `role` column in your user entity

Comment: I think i am going to update the question...  i have a table Game with owner field(one user) and players field (Many users) .... so i also have game_players table to handle the last relation